# Are restaurants, clubs and attractions open in Kyiv these days?

Tags: covid-19, kyiv

During the 10-20 of March, 2021, are restaurants, clubs and other attractions supposed to be open without significant restrictions?

Comment: Not sure anyone found a Covid-19 crystal ball yet. But looking at the recent trends, I would say a new lockdown is far from excluded. And given the current figures, even without lockdown, restaurants and clubs are probably the worst idea one could have.

Comment: @jcaron Mark mentions in his profile that he's from Israel and thus likely to be fully vaccinated by now. Restaurants and clubs are more than okay for vaccinated people.

Comment: Was finally made sure that vaccinated people cannot give the virus to other people?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler No, even people who have been fully vaccinated (i.e. 2 doses for most vaccines + enough time for them to take full effect) can still catch and transmit the virus, become sick and even die due to it. But the chances of each are drastically reduced, anywhere between 60% and >95% depending on which parameter, which vaccine, which age group and who you listen to.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.

Comment: @JonathanReez and perhaps other reasons too